# Office Registry Settings for Office 2013 for use with ADRMS

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-registry, microsoft-office-2013

We had ADRMS running with Office 2010 on Windows 7, between a few divisions using Trusted Publishing Domains (TPD), this made available by using a few registry changes for use in Office 2010
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772637(v=ws.10).aspx

> LicenseServerRedirection: Redirect to different servers for IRM
>   licensing. Used in the case where Trusted Publishing Domains are used
>   so an AD RMS cluster issues use licenses against publishing licenses
>   issued by another cluster.
>
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\DRM\LicenseServerRedirection
>         REG_SZ:  http://url.to.old.licensing.server/_wmcs/licensing
>         Value: http://url.to.new.licensing.server/_wmcs/licensing

We are now in the process of upgrading to Office 2013, and the scenario listed above is not working, does anyone know of the relevant registry changes to make (if there is any) to make this available for use?

It is not listed in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179103(v=office.15).aspx 
and I have tried

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\DRM\LicenseServerRedirection

> ```
>   REG_SZ:  http://url.to.old.licensing.server/_wmcs/licensing
>   Value: http://url.to.new.licensing.server/_wmcs/licensing
> ```

and still no luck.... any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, had to create some keys in a separate location on the Windows 7 PC

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159267(v=ws.10).aspx